# How to effectively hash all the columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, performance, hashlib

I play with mostly very large datasets. For our datacompare tool,  I need to hash all the columns ( not every value in the column, but the column as a whole ). I was wondering if there was a more faster way to do the hashing particularly for wide tables. For example it takes 10 minutes to hash 19M rows by 206 columns. This is what I have :

```
for c in compare_cols:
  try:
     h = hashlib.sha256(pd.util.hash_pandas_object(df[c].values())).hexdigest()
  except Exception as e:
    <exception stuff>
```

Without the pd.util inside the sha256, i get goofy values for the hash which I can't use later.

Comment: To clarify, you want to take the hash of the instance of a Pandas Series which contains all of its column values?

Comment: What purpose does it serve? I ask because maybe there is a more simple way to achieve the same thing. It just helps with understanding.

Comment: @JesseSealand : Correct. So my 19M*100 col table has columns like "A", "B", "C" etc. I want to get the hash value of "A", hash value of "B", hash value of "C" etc. I do not need every value to be hashed..but the entire column.

Comment: @JesseSealand : For context, I work in fintech with data testing. Getting  dissimilar columns quickly is crucial for processing we are doing post read.

Comment: `pd.util.hash_pandas_object` computes the hash value of each element and is not needed for numeric columns. It should only be used for non-numeric columns. Also, does it have to be SHA256? If you can use a faster hash (such as [xxhash](https://github.com/ifduyue/python-xxhash)) it will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can call  `hashlib.sha256()` on `pd.Series` directly:

Example:

```py
import hashlib

df = pd.DataFrame(list(map(str, range(20_000_000))), columns=['col1'])

print(hashlib.sha256(df['col1'].values).hexdigest())
```

Prints:

```
d0b9915c26ca6713c963e0de22554354298a5870e49e6b07488e2e39ea35e252
```

---

According to my benchmark, this takes ~70ms on my machine

Comment: @GaryChin, is this working for you?

Comment: Thanks, however, this does work BUT I find that for some data sets it provides incorrect compares hence I had to add the pd.util inside the sha256 method. So columns that should have had the same hash...didn't. Testers confirmed that with pd.util inside the right columns were getting picked up.  It could be a symptom of just the nature of the closed door python environment I have to work with. Hence I was wondering if there was some clever map or zip statement haha.

Comment: @GaryChin Can you provide small sample that compares incorrectly?

Comment: Sure give me some time. Have to do some mockups.

Comment: Sigh. This is weird on why they even would collide. I can use the 19M set : without the pdutil columns with the following dont have the same hash. N.B ( Both tables were joined, both tables were sorted with the same keys ).

"Col A" ( is literally just says "LIVE" ) : ["Live....]
"Col B" ( is an id column 10 digits long ): [ 1000012345, 1234589492...]
"ColC" ( is literally just 2 strings joined together with a dot) : ["ABC.EFG", "ABC.EFG"]

Some theories I have : Maybe sha256 hates downcasted data or categorical data??

Comment: @GaryChin Make sure the indices are also the same, or use `index=False` in `pd.util.hash_pandas_object()` to not include index in hash computation.

Comment: Oh is it. Let me try that.

Comment: This returns a hash of memory addresses, not values. Columns with the same values in the same order will have different hashes unless they share memory. If this is the desired behavior, we may need to consider whether you need to use hashing at all.

Comment: @ken: which one does? pd.util.hash_pandas_object with index = False?

Comment: @GaryChin: No, I'm referring to the code in this post, the one that doesn't use `pd.util.hash_pandas_object` and passes `pd.Series` directly to `hashlib.sha256`.

Comment: Ah i see. Yea I am going to try just pd.util and see what I get. Stay tuned.

Comment: OK folks so update : you definitely need index=True in the pd.util method, post join. Without it you get goofy results. pd.util "seems" faster than hashlib method. Have to do more tests. Also, I need to test out cells with more complex data types like dictionaries. I am going to run the 19M * 103 tonight.